# XSS VULNERABILITY FOR XML -- response.getWriter().write(xml.toString());

Tags: java, xml, xss

I need to fix a issue for xss vulnerability. the code segment is below.

```
StringBuffer xml = new StringBuffer();
                      xml.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
                      xml.append("<parent>");
                      xml.append("<child>");

                            for(int cntr=0; cntr < dataList.size(); cntr++){

                            AAAAA obj = (AAAAA) dataList.get(cntr);
                            if(obj.getStatus().equals(Constants.ACTIVE)){

                                xml.append("<accountNumber>");
                                xml.append(obj.getAccountNumber());
                                xml.append("</accountNumber>");

                                xml.append("<partnerName>");
                                xml.append(obj.getPartnerName());
                                xml.append("</partnerName>");

                                xml.append("<accountType>");
                                xml.append(obj.getAccountType());
                                xml.append("</accountType>");

                                xml.append("<priority>");
                                xml.append(obj.getPriority());
                                xml.append("</priority>");
                              }
                            }

                      xml.append("</child>");
                      xml.append("</parent>");  


                  response.getWriter().write(xml.toString());
                  response.setContentType("text/xml");
                  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

The issue is at the line having the syntax response.getWriter().write(xml.toString()); It says that it is vulnerable for xss attack. I have done sufficient home work and also installed ESAPI 2.0. but I donot know how to implement the solutions. 
Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always escape any text and attribute nodes you insert into an XML document, so I would expect to see

```
xml.append("<accountType>");
xml.append(escape(obj.getAccountType()));
xml.append("</accountType>");
```

where escape() looks after characters that need special treatment, eg. "<", "&", "]]>", and surrogate pairs.

Better still, don't construct XML by string concatenation. Use a serialization library that allows you to write

```
out.startElement("accountType");
out.text(obj.getAccountType());
out.endElement();
```

(I use a Saxon serializer with the StAX XMLStreamWriter interface when I need to do this, but there are plenty of alternatives available.)

Comment: can you please provide me the complete relevant code segment for the serialization of the xml you used

Comment: You can find an example here, search for method generateXML: https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.4/hej/net/sf/saxon/serialize/codenorm/UnicodeDataGenerator.java

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand:

```
AAAAA obj = (AAAAA) dataList.get(cntr);
```

here you have got some data from external source.
Then you've got to validate this data. Otherwise anyone can put any data there, that would cause the destruction on client side (cookies will be stolened for example).

Comment: The data in above referenced AAAAA obj = (AAAAA) dataList.get(cntr);
 is fetched from database. So how could that be manipulated, firstly. Secondly, even if I need to validate it, how to do that through ESAPI from the OWASP, please tell. One more thing, are you telling me about the stored xss vulnerability i.e. the data coming from the database may have been manipulated earlier and when ever i am fetching it i need to validate it?

Comment: You have got to validate data before store it in database if you can. Otherwise you should validate it when you getting it from database.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER--  the code using the ESAPI is below.
xml.append(ESAPI.encoder().encodeForXML(desc));
It will escape the data in the variable 'desc'. By the implementation of this, the content in the variable 'desc' will be readed as data not executable code and hence the data will not get executed in the browser on the response of the back end java code.